# how can i hide dropdown menu by clicking outside using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a simple dropdown script and I want it to hide all open dropdowns on a click outside of the menu. But it does not seem to work, does anyone know why? i use only html css and Javascript no jQuery or Bootstrap

```
    function showerClickSub() {
    document.getElementById("my-sub").classList.toggle("show");
    document.getElementById("my-sub1").classList.remove("show");
    }
    function showerClickSub() {
        document.getElementById("my-sub").classList.toggle("show");
        document.getElementById("my-sub1").classList.remove("show");
    }
    function showerClickSub1() {
        document.getElementById("my-sub1").classList.toggle("show");
        document.getElementById("my-sub").classList.remove("show");
    }

    //   Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    document.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.sub-menu')) {
        let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-active");
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
        }
    }

        <nav class="navBar navBar-active">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#" onClick="showerClickSub()">Services<span class="arrow-down"></span></a>
                    <ul id="my-sub"  class="dropdown-content">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub-menu1"><a href="#" onClick="showerClickSub1()">Service area<span class="arrow-down"></span></a>
                    <ul id="my-sub1" class="sub-active1" >
                        <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home7</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: You should really include some of your code and explain what the problem is. Otherwise is not possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? Basically you create a trigger to slide up the dropdown list on click of the document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-align: left;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #939393;
}

ul li ul.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 100%;
  /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
}

ul li ul.dropdown-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">dropdown &#9662;</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```